# Using an older font in WPF

Tags: wpf, fonts, font-family

I have several older FON files that I'd like to use in WPF.  So far, though, I haven't been able to load them.  If I load the file as a FontFamily, WPF doesn't complain, but it actually substitutes a standard font in place of the one it supposedly loaded.

```
public static FontFamily Load()
{
    return new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/Fonts/12x24"), "Console");
}
```

If I try to load the file as a GlyphTypeface, I get an error saying it isn't a supported type of font.  (If I double-click on the file in Windows explorer, it pops up in some sort of system dialog that offers "Print" or "Install" options, so some part of the operating system knows how to read this file....)

I've spotted one FontConverter application, but they want $170 for it....

So, I'm looking for some way to either convert this file to something WPF likes, or else some way to load the file so that WPF will let me use it.